# How to make ignore function remove the delimiter as well

Tags: c++, c-strings

I wanted to grab a 10 character and store it in cstring and ignore the rest but I have having problem with it. The program doesn't halt for input the next time. How can I make it so that it halts and lets me enter again.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   char arr[11] = " "; //This is a cstring
   string x; //will test with this variable

   cout <<"Enter 10 character, rest will be ignored: \n";
   cin.getline(arr, 10,'\n');  
   cin.ignore();

   cout <<"Testing..\n";
   cin >>x;            //Should make the program halt

   cout <<arr <<endl;
   cout <<x;

}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just `std::getline` into the `std::string`, without any further pleasantries, then check `size()`, and if it's more than 10, lop off the extra part?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am learning cstring. I know i could just use standard string but wanted to play around with cstring.

Comment: `std::getline` is a C++ library function. `std::string` is a C++ class. Using a C++ library function with a C++ class is the simplest use case. Although `std::getline` has some extra parameters that can be used to modify it's behavior, in practice unless one fully understand the fine details of iostreams behavior, status, and error recovery, using `std::getline` un-naturally, like this, is an endless rabbithole. If you insist on C-style `char` arrays, it's going to be simpler to `get()` one character at a time, inspect it, and place it into your `char` array, under controlled conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.getline(arr, 10,'\n')` will output at most 9 characters, not 10 characters, stopping if a line break is read before reaching 9 characters.  If you want to receive 10 characters, you need to set the `count` parameter to 11 - the full size of `arr` - to include room for 10 characters + the null terminator.

Calling `cin.ignore()` afterwards without any parameters will ignore only 1 character.  So, if the user types in more than `count+1` characters, you are not ignoring them all.  You should tell `cin.ignore()` to ignore all characters up to the next line break, if no line break was reached during the read.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char arr[11]; //This is a cstring
    string x; //will test with this variable

    cout << "Enter 10 character, rest will be ignored: \n";
    if (cin.getline(arr, 11, '\n'))
    {
        // <= 10 characters w/ line break were read
    }
    else
    {
        if (cin.fail() && !cin.bad()) // exactly 10 characters w/o a line break were read, ignore the rest...
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }

   cout << "Testing..\n";
   cin >> x;            //Should make the program halt

   cout << arr << endl;
   cout << x;
}
```

That being said, this is C++, not C.  It would be easier to use `std::getline()` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str; //This is a c++ string
    string x; //will test with this variable

    cout << "Enter 10 character, rest will be ignored: \n";
    getline(cin, str);

    if (str.size() > 10)
        str.resize(10);

    cout << "Testing..\n";
    cin >> x;            //Should make the program halt

    cout << str << endl;
    cout << x;
}
```